# Why can't I just create MutableState outside a composable?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

So my understanding is that it is bad practice:

```
var num by mutableStateOf(0)

@Composable
fun Counter() {
    Column{
        Text(text = "$num")
        Button(onClick = {
            num++
        }){
            Text("Count")
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the proper way from docs and community:

```
@Composable
fun Counter() {

    var num by remember{mutableStateOf(0)}

    Column{
        Text(text = "$num")
        Button(onClick = {
            num++
        }){
            Text("Count")
        }
    }
}
```

So I am hoping someone can break it down for me.

First, why don't we ever see examples of the first approach, I mean we made the composable stateless, isn't that a good thing?

Second, I understand how ViewModels and state hoisting works, but again wouldn't it just be simpler to create a file with all my mutable state objects and call is MyStates.kt or something?

Third, is it only because of code unpredictability and poor encapsulation that we don't see the first approach often? If so, I just find this hard to understand without seeing a working example of why the first approach is a poor option.

Thanks

Comment: Those are both fine. What made you think declaring mutable state outside of composition is the wrong thing to do (that's exactly what you do when hoisting state into a ViewModel)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Well we only see examples of hoisting state in either a ViewModel or in a parent composable, not the example I showed

Comment: The main problem of global state as in the first example is that it is, well, global. So if you want to show multiple counters, they will all have the same state, the same count, which you typically don't want.

Answer (score 1):

First question, it same as when you are using data from viewModel.

Second question, when the project is getting larger and more complex. You might need so much state for your screens. You will have an issue to manage all your states in one file. Also it naming might be complicated. That's also one of why separation of concern exist.

Third, sometimes people have to save their value from activity lifecycle like screen rotation using **rememberSaveable**. To make all the code is uniformed, all object should be placed at same place (inside composable).

So far, thats all i know.
Correct me if i'm wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bad practice to storing `MutableState` out of Composable but it's often done with a class that hold several `MutableState`s or classes that hold also `MutableState`s and it's a general pattern in default rememberX functions such as `rememberScrollState`, `rememberLazyListState` and so on.

LazyListState for instance, holds `MutableState`s and `LazyListScrollPosition` which also hold its `MutableState`s.

https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/foundation/foundation/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyListState.kt;drc=ba1a8c00dd0edf12d70eca6267c1d744a6f30abc;l=143

Also in Google example JetSnack you can see MutableStates

```
@Stable
class SearchState(
    query: TextFieldValue,
    focused: Boolean,
    searching: Boolean,
    categories: List<SearchCategoryCollection>,
    suggestions: List<SearchSuggestionGroup>,
    filters: List<Filter>,
    searchResults: List<Snack>
) {
    var query by mutableStateOf(query)
    var focused by mutableStateOf(focused)
    var searching by mutableStateOf(searching)
    var categories by mutableStateOf(categories)
    var suggestions by mutableStateOf(suggestions)
    var filters by mutableStateOf(filters)
    var searchResults by mutableStateOf(searchResults)
    val searchDisplay: SearchDisplay
        get() = when {
            !focused && query.text.isEmpty() -> SearchDisplay.Categories
            focused && query.text.isEmpty() -> SearchDisplay.Suggestions
            searchResults.isEmpty() -> SearchDisplay.NoResults
            else -> SearchDisplay.Results
        }
}
```

https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/64b21939fc86968e1a1d82b72072b4895e2cc743/Jetsnack/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetsnack/ui/home/search/Search.kt#L153

This approach is often used with Composable or Modifiers to encapsulate ui logic and to trigger recomposition when required.

In my Cropper library i pass wrapper class that encapsulates MutableStates and logic for other operations as

https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-Cropper/blob/e35a57378752ad32f688f3e8f0bd4234ca6cb630/cropper/src/main/java/com/smarttoolfactory/cropper/state/CropStateImpl.kt#L47

ViewModel is often used for storing MutableStates or/and Flows of business logic or passing data from domain or data layer based on how code is structured, that's it's often seen in sample codes. But when you build a ui library or your Custom Composable or Modifier free of long ui logic first approach is often preferred.

Answer (score -1):

**first approach:**

```
var num by mutableStateOf(0)
```

If you define it this way, when recompose is performed, the stored value will be forgotten and the initial value you gave will become 0. In short, the current value you kept will be lost when recompose occurs.

**second approach:**

```
  var num by remember{mutableStateOf(0)}
```

If you define it this way, it does not forget the registered value when it recomposes, so for example, let your num value be 3 and it still remains 3 when it recomposes.

Also, keeping it in viewmodel might be a better approach, as you said, the reason for this is to avoid complexity if you have too many state variables. For example, imagine that you have 15 state variables, keeping them as you mentioned above would cause a very complicated appearance, wouldn't it?
If you have few variables, you can do it as you said above